# Koch Snowflake in Python won't work

Tags: python, matplotlib, fractals

I'm having a problem with this Python program. It's supposed to draw a Koch-Snowflake with n iterations. The code does compile but it won't draw a snowflake and I can't find my mistake.

I'd be very thankful if anyone could help me out with this!

```
from math import sqrt
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

class vector:
    def __init__(self,one,two):
        self.x = one
        self.y = two

    def printV(self):
        s = "(" + str(self.x) + "," + str(self.y) + ")"
        print s

    def __len__(self):
        l = sqrt(self.x**2 + self.y**2)
        return l

def kochSnowflakeImpl(p1,p2):
    u = vector(p1.x + p2.x - p1.x, p1.y + p2.y - p1.y)
    array = []

    #calculate n1
    n1 = vector(p1.x + 1.0/3.0 * u.x, p1.y + (1.0/3.0) * u.y)

    #calculate n2
    n2 = vector(p1.x + 2.0/3.0 * u.x,p1.y + 2.0/3.0 * u.y)

    v = vector(n1.y + n2.y - n1.y, -(n1.x + n2.x - n1.x)) #is an  orthogonal vector to u

    #calculate n3
    n3 = vector(n1.x + 0.5*u.x + sqrt(3.0)/2.0 * v.x, p1.y + 0.5*u.y + sqrt(3.0)/2.0* v.y)

    array.append([n1.x,n1.y])
    array.append([n2.x,n2.y])
    array.append([n3.x,n3.y])
    return n1,n2,n3,array

def kochSnowflake(level):
    p1 = vector(0,0) #format: p = (x,y)
    p2 = vector(1,0)
    p3 = vector(0.5,sqrt(3)/2)
    array = [[p1.x,p1.y],[p2.x,p2.y],[p3.x,p3.y],[p1.x,p1.y]]

    while level > 0:
        if level == 1:
            n1,n2,n3,array1 = kochSnowflakeImpl(p1,p2)
            n4,n5,n6,array2 = kochSnowflakeImpl(p2,p3)
            n7,n8,n9,array3 = kochSnowflakeImpl(p3,p2)
            for i in array1:
                array.append(i)
            for j in array2:
                array.append(j)
            for k in array3:
                array.append(k)
        else:
            n1,n2,n3,array1 = kochSnowflakeImpl(p1,p2)
            n11,n21,n31,array11 = kochSnowflakeImpl(n1,n3)
            n12,n22,n32,array12 = kochSnowflakeImpl(n3,n2)

            n4,n5,n6,array2 = kochSnowflakeImpl(p2,p3)
            n41,n52,n61,array21 = kochSnowflakeImpl(n4,n6)
            n42,n52,n62,array22 = kochSnowflakeImpl(n6,n5)

            n7,n8,n9,array3 = kochSnowflakeImpl(p1,p3)
            n71,n81,n91,array31 = kochSnowflakeImpl(n7,n9)
            n72,n82,n92,array32 = kochSnowflakeImpl(n9,n8)

            for i in array1:
                array.append(i)
            for i in array11:
                array.append(i)
            for i in array12:
                array.append(i)
            for j in array2:
                array.append(j)
            for j in array21:
                array.append(j)
            for j in array22:
                array.append(j)
            for k in array3:
                array.append(k)
            for k in array31:
                array.append(k)
            for k in array32:
                array.append(k)
        level -= 1
    return array

if __name__=='__main__':
    points = kochSnowflake(5)
    x,y = zip(*points)
    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: What testing have you done? What works, what doesn't? Do `x` and `y` contain the correct values (also, you can just do `x, y = zip(*points)`)?

Comment: Indentions are incorect in your code - so don't write `"I really hope the code indentation is still correct"` but correct this.

Comment: If you have problem with formating on forum - format this in your editor (use 4 spaces in place of tab) and copy-paste correct version.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I have not done any real testing because I didn't know how I could do that. I don't have a function that generates all needed points, that I could use to check my results. I x and y should contain the right values if my calculation works. What seems to be working is dividing the sides of my initial triangle into 3 eqally long parts - so the main problem is probably calculating the "nook" and properly drawing it, i.e. deleting the middle part. I can indeed use ´x,y = zip(*points)´ and it plots the same thing. Thank you for your response!

Comment: @Eve413 well what do you get instead? Could you provide an image? If you can't describe precisely what is wrong, it is difficult to figure out where the error is.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: It's hard to describe... it's basically the triangle with a lot of lines going all over the place. I tried uploading an image but since I don't have "10 reputation" I cannot do that... I'm sorry!

Comment: I think you need to look through the implementation... for example `vector(p1.x + p2.x - p1.x, p1.y + p2.y - p1.y)` The first term is just p2.x and the second term is just p1.y.  That doesn't seem right (at least it is inefficient :-) ).  That type of thing happens a few times in the code (e.g., `v = vector(n1.y + n2.y - n1.y...`)

Answer (score 0):

I decided it was time to turn the output of this code from a bad piece of string art from the '70s that didn't age well in the closet into a Koch snowflake.

One problem is the OP added new points to the array in `kochSnowflakeImpl()` but forgot to add the original start and end points.  The next problem was the `n3` calculation as the two terms that summed to make each coordinate were from the same coordinate whereas one term should have been from the other coordinate.  And the level logic in `kochSnowflake()` was hopeless.

To simplify the code, I tossed the OP's `vector` class (which was reasonable) and substituted the more complete `Vec2D` class from Python turtle:

```
from turtle import Vec2D
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

SQRT_3 = 3.0 ** 0.5

def kochSnowflakeImpl(p1, p2):
    u = p2 - p1
    v = Vec2D(-u[1], u[0])

    n1 = p1 + u * (1.0 / 3.0)
    n2 = n1 + u * (1.0 / 6.0) + v * (SQRT_3 / 6.0)
    n3 = p1 + u * (2.0 / 3.0)

    return [p1, n1, n2, n3, p2]

def kochSnowflake(level):
    p1 = Vec2D(0.0, 0.0)
    p2 = Vec2D(0.5, SQRT_3 / 2.0)
    p3 = Vec2D(1.0, 0.0)

    array = [p1, p2, p3, p1]

    for _ in range(level):
        new_array = []

        for (p1, p2) in zip(array, array[1:]):
            new_array.extend(kochSnowflakeImpl(p1, p2))

        array = new_array

    return array

if __name__ == '__main__':
    points = kochSnowflake(4)
    x, y = zip(*points)
    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.show()
```

I don't think this code is quite correct as the snowflake looks a bit squat, but I believe it achieves the goal of the original code and is clean enough to build upon.

[image]

Comment: It will look better if you set the axis as equal